generating App only token fails with error code AADSTS500011
I am trying to create an app-only token by using.
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BtenantId%7D}/oauth2/token

with the parameters "client_id", client_secret, scope, grant_type="client_credentials", and resource.
What verification does it perform for the "resource" parameter?
When I use resource as an Azure relay URL (https://mytesting.servicebus.windows.net) it works fine and generates a token. A relay Azure resource is created in a separate Tenant and not in {TenantId}. and mytesting.servicebus.windows.net is not provisioned in {TenantId}, but still the token can be generated.
But when I use resource as my Web App URI (https://myApp.azurewebsites.net) it fails with the message:

AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://myApp.azurewebsites.net.azurewebsites.net was not found in the tenant named {tenantId}

Why can I get a token for my Azure relay URI, without provisioning this resource in tenant, but the resource URI for my Azure app fails for generating a token?
I don't want to provision my resource in customer tenant.

I created an Azure web app and added Microsoft as the identity provider:

I generated access token via Postman passing resource as https://MyApp.azurewebsites.net and got the same error:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
resource:https://rukwebapp33.azurewebsites.net



AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://rukwebapp33.azurewebsites.net was not found in the tenant named Contoso. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid resource/scope to generate the access token.
To resolve the error, you need to pass resource as the Application ID/ClientID of the Microsoft Entra application which is added as an identity provider for the Web app.

OR you can also get the App ID from the overview page of the Microsoft Entra application:

Now when I pass the resource as an Application ID of the application, I got the access token successfully:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
resource:ClientID


By using the above access token, I am able to call the Web App successfully:
GET https://rukwebapp33.azurewebsites.net


References:
javascript - Error: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named "URL" was not found in the tenant - Stack Overflow by juunas
How to Secure an Azure App Service with Azure AD Authentication by Carl de Souza

Hi Rukmini, thanks for reply. My question was how for Azure relay it is working to generate token when i have not associated any Entra AppId with Azure Relay.

Azure Relay uses Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to authenticate and authorize access to its resources. When a security principal (a user, group, or application) attempts to access a Relay entity, the request must be authorized

These tokens grant access to specific resources or operations

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-authentication-and-authorization#microsoft-entra-id
